# Getting Configuration file config.hocon does not exist when running Docker image (Snowplow, Scala)

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, cube.js, snowplow

Using an AWS EC2 with Docker installed, I am trying to run a docker image using the following code:

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD/scala-stream-collector-config:/snowplow/config \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  snowplow/scala-stream-collector-kinesis:1.0.1 \
  --config /snowplow/config/config.hocon
```

My config.hocon file is in the route directory. I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Configuration file config.hocon does not exist
```

I think my issue is I am not sure where to put the config.hocon file. I have tried to place the file in different folders and played with the --config line.

This is the first time that I am doing this, so if it appears there is something basic I am missing that is likely true.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have to make sure the file is copied into the container before

Comment: @cchantep config.hocon passed to container though mounted volume, it does not have to be copied into container.

Answer (score 2):

`config.hocon` needs to be in `$PWD/scala-stream-collector-config/`.

This directory will be mounted in `/snowplow/config` in the Docker container and `--config /snowplow/config/` will point to it.